# MySQL order by primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, primary-key

Some SQL servers allow for a generic statement such as `ORDER BY PRIMARY KEY`.  I don't believe this works for MySQL, is there any such workaround that would allow for automated selects across multiple tables or does it require a lookup query to determine the primary key?

The workaround I have been working on involves calling a `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` before running the query.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Can MySQL determine the primary key of a table during the select process?

**Update:**  There is no official way of doing this in MySQL or SQL in general as Gordon pointed out.  SAP has custom functionality for it.  There are workarounds, such as working with `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` or the `information_schema` as John pointed out.

Comment: If you do not know what the key is, why do you want to order by it?  And, what database supports that syntax?  I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Because the reports are to be generated using the primary key.  Most all tables are constructed with sorting in mind.  However, MySQL does not provide a default sorting order, only defaults to how/when they are inserted.

Comment: . . That is correct; it is the ANSI SQL way of doing things.  Tables and results sets represent unordered sets -- unless you explicitly include the `order by` clause at the outermost level.  The syntax you mention does not exists in any database that I know of because the `from` clause can reference multiple tables.  There would be multiple choices for a primary key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've used it in SAP with OpenSQL.  I believe in the case of joins, it references the first table, but I'd have to verify.  Right now I'm using PHP/MySQL for this task.

Comment: How would a default order work with a GROUP BY query that spans several tables, and not a single primary key is represented in the columns of that result? Even if such a feature does exist in one dbms it does not mean it is sensible and that you should expect this behaviour in others. You should treat every resultset as unordered UNTIL you apply the `ORDER BY` clause; and this may be anything that makes sense in the context of that specific query.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, I'm not asking for a default order or running group by queries.  I'm asking for a order by primary key for generation of reports based on hundreds of tables.  My question was involving `ORDER BY` but an automated approach using the primary key of the table...

Comment: @GordonLinoff interestingly enough, it seems mysqldump has an `--order-by-primary` option: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_order-by-primary.  Just came across that today randomly.

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646523/mysql-order-by-primary-key-dynamically-in-desc-order

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL generally pulls data out by insertion order which would be by primary key, but that aside you technically can do the same thing if you pull out the primary key column name and put it in an order by

```
SELECT whatever FROM table
ORDER BY
(   SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
    FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName')
      AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName')
      AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')
);
```

For composite keys you can use this

```
SELECT whatever FROM table
ORDER BY
(   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName')
      AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName')
      AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')
);
```

Permission for information schema access from the [**DOCS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)

> Each MySQL user has the right to access these tables, but
>   can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for
>   which the user has the proper access privileges. In some cases (for
>   example, the ROUTINE_DEFINITION column in the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table), users who have insufficient
>   privileges see NULL. These restrictions do not apply for InnoDB
>   tables; you can see them with only the PROCESS privilege.
>
> The same privileges apply to selecting information from
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA and viewing the same information through SHOW
>   statements. In either case, you must have some privilege on an object
>   to see information about it.

### SETUP:

```
CREATE TABLE some_stuff (
    firstID INT,
    secondID INT,
    username varchar(55),
    PRIMARY KEY (firstID, secondID)
) ;
```

### QUERY:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'some_stuff')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

### OUTPUT:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME` SEPARATOR ', ') |
+--------------------------------------------+
|              firstID, secondID             |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: . . This just won't work.  You could do something similar'ish with dynamic SQL.  But do remember composite primary keys.

Comment: @GordonLinoff composite primary keys would cause this to not work.. but i just tested locally and it executes just fine.

Comment: Composite keys will be needed for my use but I'll upvote it for future users who come across this and don't need composite.

Comment: @Devon thanks I reciprocated the +1 :) see my edit for a way to do it with composite keys

Comment: Thank you.  For informational purposes, does a user need administrative access to access information_schema?

Comment: @JohnRuddell, thank you.  That looks to be a good solution.  I'm going to read deeper into this and see if it will work for me.

Comment: @Devon if this answer solved your issue I would greatly appreciate it if you accepted it! :)

Comment: Nice! I wish mysql had a magic word that always meant "primary key" so you could "select .... order by magic_word_primary_key" - but since they don't you're solution is tops!

Thanks @JohnRuddell

Comment: looking at your SQL I believe the composite solution should work even for tables without a composite primary key - really great stuff

Answer (score 2):

SAP does, indeed do this (http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/fc/eb3a53358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm). SQL Server is also based on Sybase, and I don't think Sybase supported this functionality. There are many limitations on the syntax.

On a query on one table with a primary key, no explicit `order by`, and no `where` conditions, MySQL will generally return the results in primary key order. You cannot depend on this functionality, but it might be good enough for your system.

The big issue would be the use of indexes for the `where` clause. If there are no indexes on the table, you don't have to worry about it. If there are, you could possibly emulate the behavior with a materialized view:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from table t
     ) t
where <where clause here>;
```

Another option is to force the database engine to use the primary key index. You can do this by using a [`force index` hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html). The issue is that you need to know the name of the index.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Gordon, useful as always.  I may have unrealistic expectations in this approach, just trying to save an extra query if possible but SHOW COLUMNS seems to be pretty quick so I may just stay with my workaround.