# MySQL ORDER BY whatever_is_the_first_field DESC or inverse MySQL default sorting

Tags: mysql

How to do this in MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Without having to SELECT the first or any column or knowing how its Primary key looks like.

Note: I know this is a bad practice but it is an access protected file & meant to be used by devs only and for for test proposes. kind of a quick retrieve of 10 last rows from different databases `db_tests.php?fct=lastTen&db=mssql_2&table=t_user`

---

UPDATE: The full query is :

```
select * from t_user LIMIT 10 order by 1 desc
```

Comment: It's not clear what's the issue you are having. What you wrote works fine.

Comment: @Icarus: He's trying to order by the first field, without explicitly writing out that field's name... for some reason.

Comment: You could look in `information_schema` to get the primary key.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26149174

Comment: Your code works for me. What's the problem?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I forgot about `information_schema` I'll try it to retrieve 'whatever is' first column name. thanks

Comment: "MySQL default sorting" is not a thing. A query can return rows in different orders when run multiple times. Tables in SQL are unordered collections.

Comment: @Icarus : it worked fine with MS SQL but not with MySQL. errorInfo() is outputting : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY 1 DESC' at line 1 )

Comment: @Barmar with MySQL is working only when I select fields like and not with `select *`

Comment: Post the **exact** MySQL query that you have problem with.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani What version of MySQL? I tried it with 5.5 and it worked.

Comment: @Barmar version is 5.1.53-community and working on IIS 6.5 (windows server)

Comment: @Barmar Sorry I did wrong comment. even with selecting fields order by 1 is not working

Comment: In that case I suspect you have a different problem, that should work. My guess is you have your clauses in the wrong order. Post the whole query.

Comment: @SalemOuerdani Don't put the problem in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: Swap `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your clauses in the wrong order.
You have to put the `LIMIT` clause **after** the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM t_user
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Yes that was my mistake ! thanks ! working too much with frameworks make you forget things ! thanks again !