# MySQL order by primary key dynamically in DESC order

Tags: java, mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I am trying to query a table in descending order based on its primary key column.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats
ORDER BY 
( SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') 
 ) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I am expecting this query to return rows in descending order. However it is not working as expected. I feel DESC is not being applied to the query. 
The reason I am writing query in this fashion is, I wanted to use this query in my Java code and it will parameterized function like:

```
public void myFunction(String dbName, String tableName);
```

Because at run time I will not be knowing what will be the primary key of a table. However I am supplying only 2 parameters dbname and tablename. Hence fetching primary key column name using following sub-query:

```
( SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') 
 )
```

Above query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats ORDER BY VitalsMasterKey DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Which returns result in descending order as expected.

Can anyone please help me in correcting the query and get output in descending order. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How about separating this into two steps? First fetch primary column name, then query result ordered by this column.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying desc to inner query .

Comment: I applied to inner query but did not work. Can you show query please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
set @Query1=Concat('SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats ORDER BY ', (SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
    FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
      AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
      AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')),' desc limit 10');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @Query1; 
 EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you give it to me in plain sql format as it is SP.

Comment: It is working but I want to use this in Java code and will be executed using JdbcTemplate. So Is there any alternative to concat()?

Comment: first use concat() and let us know if any issue

Comment: @mahendrakawde what you have missed is that you cannot mix data with the query. In sql you cannot use data (e.g. the name of the primary key returned as a string by the subquery) to become part of the outer query's sql code and order the resultset by it. Period. The workaround in MySQL is what this answer demonstrates: retrieve the name of the primary key first and then dynamically create the other sql statement via string concatenation using this piece of data and execute it. You can do the same in java as well: first retrieve the pk, then assemble the actual sql statement and then execute it

Comment: The above is a pure sql code and should be executable from java as well. Whether it is suitable for java template, I do not know. However, the query hints at a serious design flaw: why on Earth don't you know what the PK is for a given table? The table structures should not change on a whim.

Comment: Because I will fetch records from any table dynamically. Hence I dont know what would be its PK.

Comment: You will have the same problem if you want to substitute the table name dynamically into the query: you cannot mix data and structure. You have to determine which table you select from and substitute that into the sql query before it is executed. The only additional thing you need to do is to fetch the PK field name(s) for that given table and dynamically add it (them) to the query - again before it is executed. And note, that you may have multiple fields in a PK.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write prepare statement

```
SET @col = '';
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` INTO @col
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats ORDER BY ',@col,' DESC LIMIT 10');
PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats
ORDER BY 
( SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') 
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC LIMIT 10;
) ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This should do. You are missing on which you need to apply desc function in the inner query.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But sad to say that it is not working and even Limit is not working. However in my query I am able to limit it atleast. Thanks for help mate. But do you have any idea what I am missing.

Comment: Did you tried passing the column name on the outer query on which you want to sort ?
SELECT * FROM fdmsus_demo.vitalstats
ORDER BY 
( SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'fdmsus_demo')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'vitalstats')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') 
 ) 'COLUMN_NAME' DESC LIMIT 10;

Comment: No even this is not working. COLUMN_NAME on outer query will be column name fetched from inner query.

Comment: did you also tried using join??
SELECT v.VID, v.thumb
FROM video AS v
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT VID
     FROM video
     WHERE title LIKE "%'.$Channel['name'].'%"
     ORDER BY viewtime DESC
     LIMIT 5) as v2
  ON v.VID = v2.VID
ORDER BY RAND() (or) (column_name)
LIMIT 1

Comment: @mahendrakawde
select * from user_permission where id IN(select id from users order by id) order by id limit 5;
| id | user_id | permission        
|  1 |      -1 | abc         |            
|  2 |      -1 | abcde |            
|  3 |      -1 | abcd       |            
|  4 |      -1 | abcdw      |           
|  5 |      -1 | ab    |            
+----+---------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

I tried on my local, it worked. Can you check whether this works in your case, if not can let me know what else is missing ?

Comment: @mahendrakawde did your problem solved ?? if yes how? or did you checked on the above one?